# Polish name (Wężarów) returned from json service as W\u0119\u017car\u00f3w, renders as WÄ™Å¼arÃ³w. Can't figure out encoding/charset.

Tags: encoding, character-encoding

I'm using DB-IP.com to get city names from IP addresses. Many of these are international cities, with special characters in the names.

As an example, one of these cities is Wężarów in Poland. Checking the JSON return in the console or opening the request URL directly, it's being returned from DB-IP as "W\u0119\u017car\u00f3w" with a Content-Type of text/javascript;charset=UTF-8. This is rendered in the browser as WÄ™Å¼arÃ³w - it is also saved in my mysql database as WÄ™Å¼arÃ³w (which I've tried with both utf8 and latin1 encoding).

I'm ok with saving it in the DB as another format, as long as I can convert it back to Wężarów for display in browser. I've tried encoding and decoding to/from several formats, even just to display directly on the screen (ignoring the DB entirely). I'm completely confused on what I need to do here to get it in readable format.

I'm working with PERL, however if I can figure out what I need to do with the encoding/decoding/charset (as I'm currently clueless), I'm sure I can figure it out from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the UTF-8 encoded string was interpreted by the browser as if it were Windows-1252. Here's how I deduced it:

```
% python3
>>> s = "W\u0119\u017car\u00f3w"
>>> b = bytes(s, encoding='utf-8')
>>> b
b'W\xc4\x99\xc5\xbcar\xc3\xb3w'
>>> str(b, encoding='utf-8')
'Wężarów'
>>> str(b, encoding='latin-1')
'WÄ\x99Å¼arÃ³w'
>>> str(b, encoding='windows-1252')
'WÄ™Å¼arÃ³w'
```

If you're not good with Python, what I'm doing here is encoding the string `"W\u0119\u017car\u00f3w"` into UTF-8, yielding the byte sequence `'W\xc4\x99\xc5\xbcar\xc3\xb3w'`. Decoding that with UTF-8 yielded `'Wężarów'`, confirming that this is the correct UTF-8 encoding of the string you want. So I took a guess that the browser is using the wrong encoding to render it, and decoded it using Latin-1. That gave me something very close, so I looked up [Latin-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) and noticed that it's named as the basis for Windows-1252. Decoding again as Windows-1252 gives the result you saw.

What's gone wrong here is that the browser can't tell what encoding to use to render the page, and it's guessing wrong. You need to fix this by telling it explicitly to use UTF-8. [Here's a page by the W3C](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-encoding-declarations) that describes how to do that. Essentially what you need to do is add an HTML `<meta>` element to the document head. If you also set an HTTP header with the encoding name in it, make sure they are consistent.

(In Firefox, while you're debugging, you can go to View -> Character Encoding to set the encoding on a page-by-page basis. I assume other browsers have the same feature.)

Comment: All fixed with `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>` It was a page in a CMS which is explicitly set to iso-8859-1, so I had to hack the core a bit to get it to work, but looks good :) Spent so much time trying to adjust the coding inline....